# AmbiguousMatchException exception in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

PFB my code.

```
namespace ManualCSharpe
{
    public class MyServices : Service
    {
        [Route("/L/hello/")] //RequestDTO one
        public class HelloL
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        [Route("/H/hello/")] //RequestDTO two
        public class HelloH
        {
            public string Name1 { get; set; }
        }
        public class HelloResponse //ResponseDTO
        {
            public string Result { get; set; }
        }

        public class HelloServiceL : Service //Service One
        {
            public object Get(HelloL request)
            {
                return new HelloResponse { Result = "Low" };
            }
         }
        public class HelloServiceH : Service //Service 
        {
            public object Get(HelloH request)
            {
                return new HelloResponse { Result = "High" };
            }
        }

        //Define the Web Services AppHost
        public class AppHost : AppSelfHostBase
        {
            public AppHost()
                : base("HttpListener Self-Host",new Assembly[] {typeof(HelloServiceL).Assembly, typeof(HelloServiceH).Assembly}) { }


            public override void Configure(Funq.Container container) { }
        }

        //Run it!
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listeningOn = args.Length == 0 ? "http://*:133/" : args[0];
            var appHost = new AppHost()
                .Init()
                .Start(listeningOn);

            Console.WriteLine("AppHost Created at {0}, listening on {1}",
                DateTime.Now, listeningOn);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I am tring to added two service then it is show below exception.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in ServiceStack.dll

Additional information: Could not register Request 'ManualCSharpe.MyServices+HelloL' with service 'ManualCSharpe.MyServices+HelloServiceL' as it has already been assigned to another service.

Each Request DTO can only be handled by 1 service.
```

I have below douts.

1. Here I have created two different DTO for Two Service. Why it is showing error like `Each Request DTO can only be handled by 1 service.` In simple word, `Two route` mapped with `two DTO with two Service`.
2. Can I create one route for multiple RequestDTO with multiple service? In Simple word, One Route`/L/hello/` can be mapped with two DTO `HelloL` and `HelloH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have Service class implementations nested inside another outer MyServices class:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    [Route("/L/hello/")] //RequestDTO one
    public class HelloL
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    [Route("/H/hello/")] //RequestDTO two
    public class HelloH
    {
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class HelloResponse //ResponseDTO
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }

    public class HelloServiceL : Service //Service One
    {
        public object Get(HelloL request)
        {
            return new HelloResponse { Result = "Low" };
        }
     }
    public class HelloServiceH : Service //Service 
    {
        public object Get(HelloH request)
        {
            return new HelloResponse { Result = "High" };
        }
    }
}
```

Remove the outer MyServices class completely and just have the DTO's and Service classes directly under a C# namespace.

Also routes shouldn't end with a `/` suffix, so I'd change:

```
[Route("/L/hello/")]
```

to:

```
[Route("/L/hello")]
```

Comment: Thanks.. My second question is `Can I create one route for multiple RequestDTO with multiple service? In Simple word, One Route/L/hello/ can be mapped with two DTO HelloL and HelloH.`

Comment: @chirag they can't be exactly the same route (as expected), they need to differ by VERB - i.e. the 2nd parameter. `[Route("/L/hello","GET")]` and `[Route("/L/hello","POST")]`

Answer (score 2):

@mythz answer is correct for OP but I came here looking for an answer for a different situation which the cause was not particularly obvious - you will get this exception if you attempt to register the same assembly twice, for example, if you move a service implementation into the same assembly and were pulling it in like so:

```
 public AppHost() : base("App", typeof(AdminService).GetAssembly(), typeof(InboundService).GetAssembly(),typeof(ProductService).GetAssembly())
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who come here from a google search, a `AmbiguousMatchException` exception in ServiceStack can sometimes be triggered within ServiceStack but handled internally.

You can change your exception setting so it doesn't break on this exception.

I had changed my exception setting to break on all exceptions and this had me stuck for a while.